# What's the best way to override the project allocation process

Tags: acumatica

Regarding the 'Run Allocations by Projects' process - I have a customization where I'd like to add conditions to the Allocation process so that it doesn't execute unless those conditions are met.  I've added a checkbox user field to the 'Allocation Rules' screen (PM207500), and I'd like that field to be used (in combination with other criteria) to determine whether or not to actually execute the Allocation for that PMTask row.

I've overriden the PMAllocator.Execute method as follows, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.  Here is the code I've come up with in an extension of the PMAllocator graph:

```
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void Execute(List<PMTask> tasks)
    {
        Base.PreselectAccountGroups();
        if (Base.PreSelectTasksTransactions(tasks))
        {
            foreach (PMTask task in tasks)
            {
                //Get the allocation id for the task...
                var pmalloc = (PMAllocation)PXSelect<PMAllocation,
                                            Where<PMAllocation.allocationID, Equal<Required<PMAllocation.allocationID>>>>.Select(Base, task.AllocationID);
                //if (pmalloc == null) return;

                //Get the cache extension / user field...
                var pmallocext = PXCache<PMAllocation>.GetExtension<PMAllocationExt>(pmalloc);

                if (pmallocext.UsrRunAfterProjectCompletion == true)
                {
                    //Get the project...
                    var pmproj = (PMProject)PXSelect<PMProject,
                                            Where<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, task.ProjectID);

                    if (pmproj.ExpireDate > DateTime.Today || pmproj.ExpireDate == null)
                    {
                        //do nothing..
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Base.Execute(task, false);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Base.Execute(task, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.  It seems to be adding an extra allocation line.  I'm not really even sure if the base execute method is NOT being called if I don't explicitly call it here.

Can someone point out the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use just [PXOverride] - base Execute(...) method will be called before yours.
To replace the base method you should specify additional parameter - a delegate. In your case it can be like that:

```
public delegate void ExecuteDelegate(List<PMTask> tasks);
[PXOverride]
public virtual void Execute(List<PMTask> tasks, ExecuteDelegate BaseExecute)
{
 ... your code
}
```

Comment: so - do I have to do something with the delegate to prevent the base.execute from happening?  Or is just adding the delegate to the parameters / arguments enough to prevent the base method from executing?

Comment: just adding the delegate as a parameter is enough to prevent base method from executing.

Comment: Thanks much, Ilya!